# Pandas -unpacking several values to another columns and merging to one single Df out of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider you have the following raw df:

```
   A                      B                  
0  {'hello':'world'}   {'covid':19}          
1  {'hello':'moon'}    {'covid':23}
```

And I want to  have a result df like:

```
       hello            covid        
0      world              19            
1      moon               23
```

How do I achieve this using pandas?

If I do:

```
x = raw_df.A.dropna().apply(pd.Series)  
y = raw_df.B.dropna().apply(pd.Series)
```

I will get part of the result df , some in x and some in y.

1. How do I concatenate them in their matching indexes to be the result df I mentioned above?
2. Can I write one line to have it all? (unpack relevant columns dicts values and merge them back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
pd.concat((pd.DataFrame.from_records(x) for x in df.values.T), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   hello  covid
0  world     19
1   moon     23
```

Comment: This worked for me out of the box also for my original example! Any idea just if I want to reindex in that way `covid` column will be placed before `hello` first column as appears in raw_df?

Comment: @JavaSa Chain that with `sort_index(aixs=1)`.

Comment: can you update your anser with parameter?  I didn't succeed using it as is

Answer (score 1):

We can do `stack` and `unstack`

```
s=df.stack().apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).unstack()
   hello covid
0  world    19
1   moon    23
```

Comment: Can you please explain the double `stack` ,`unstack` , `level=1` ,`drop=True` meaning?
And if this works if we had more column aside- without need to unpack it

Comment: @JavaSa stack and unstack is one layout of pivot, for the drop level, since you have original's column with A and B , and you would like rename the dataframe with dict key , so we need drop the original name of dataframe

Comment: ok,any idea why I got on another similar example?
`{ValueError}Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @JavaSa you have two same dict key per row, that will cause the problem